# Inserting a row in SQL and setting up variables in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I was wondering if anyone knew or if it is possible to set (id, FirstName, LastName) inside the procedure below so I could insert new customers by typing...

```
CALL ('1','John','Smith');
CALL ('2', 'Jane','Smith'); and so on.
```

At the moment my code looks like this. I am using phpMyAdmin

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUpdateCustomers(id INT(10),
FirstName VARCHAR(30), 
LastName VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO customers (CustomerID, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName) VALUES (id , FirstName, LastName);
END
```

Then I call it using.

```
SET @id='1'; 
SET @FirstName='John'; 
SET @LastName='Smith'; 
CALL spUpdateCustomer(@id, @firstName, @lastName);
```

I am aiming to avoid setting each variable before every call. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: is no clear what do you want, both procedure calls works fine from phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I am using MySQL 5.6.26 in phpMyAdmin.  I'm not sure why but when I ran the code above again it worked! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to define variables for parameter values:

```
CALL spUpdateCustomer(1, 'John', 'Smith');
```

Note: The first parameter of your procedure is defined as an integer. MySQL implicitly casts '1' to 1 (string to integer). Nevertheless, if you are executing the procedure on the database server, it would be a good practice to use strictly integer values for integer parameters.